# The server has encountered a temporary p‌r‌o‌b‌l‌e‌m while setting the default version. Please try again later

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints, google-app-engine

I am getting this weird error while setting up my cloud backend

when i deployed my app, the url Http://"app-id".appspot.com
is landing on this page

[image]

**but the url http://1-dot-"app-id".appspot.com is lannding on the right page**
[image]

everything else works and its not a welcome-file issue.

then in the developer console i tried to set the default version and it gives me a error.

[image]

They say its a temporary problem but i have tried this for 2 days...
Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 3):

Found the solution after 3 days of googling and digging in settings.
This also works if your app engine project dosent have a default bucket.

go to the old developer console https://appengine.google.com/

goto main > versions and set the default version here.
the newer console didn't work for me !

Also,
goto application settings

scroll down completely till you see the title "Cloud intigration"

it reads: "Create a Google Cloud project as well as a Google Cloud Storage bucket and a new style service account for this application"

click create.

This option is not there in the newer console.